# Android: Create a layout file containing unbound elements

Tags: android, android-layout

All layout files I've seen contain some outer bounding element such as LinearLayout. I would like to create a layout file that does not contain any bounding elements. For example, all I want is to have a TextView and nothing else. I then load this in code and insert it into an existing View. Without an outer bounding element, the app will not compile. Is there some kind of outer bound element I can use that acts as a plain vanilla container with no properties? If you use LinearLayout, it will end up generating unnecessary code that my View does not require.

Comment: Weird, of course you can. I tried creating a normal xml file and added the TextView as the root element. For some reason it didn't compile. I then used the Android XML wizard to create one and it worked. Probably was a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to set the namespace of the element? The root element of any layout you declare must have this: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Also, when you have a problem like this, it will be infinitely easier to help you if you include the code in your question.